# node.firstChild.remove() drastically reduces performances

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am writing a live chat web app for Twitch website using Svelte framework, I want to set a max message history length of 800, which does not seem to have rendering problems or performance hit... until I start removing the firstChild of the content div to add in the new messages.

[Here's the Chrome performance report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5NZg.png)
and here's a screen captur (https://i.imgur.com/kTpjkny.mp4) during the test, you can see the performance hit by eye.

Following is the chat component's only function

```
messages.subscribe((childs) => {
  const content = document.querySelector('#content') as HTMLElement;

  if (childs.length > 800) {
    content.firstChild?.remove();
  }
});
```

Thank you for your help, I am pulling my hair right now

Edit:

Svelte writable function

```
const messagesWritable = () => {
  const { update, subscribe }: Writable<Message[]> = writable([]);

  return {
    addMessage: (msg: Message) =>
      update((v) => {
        if (v.length >= 800) {
          v.splice(0, 1);
        }
        return [...v, msg];
      }),
    subscribe,
  };
};
```

Comment: Have you tried letting Svelte handle DOM updates (including child node removal) by simply updating a messages FIFO buffer capped at max size 800, rather than handling DOM updates yourself?

Comment: I have no idea of what you are talking about, do you have an example to show ? Google does not seem to have an answer

Comment: In short, once a new message arrives, if your buffer is at capacity, you delete the oldest message in the buffer using `Array.shift` for instance.

Comment: I understand now, I actually did something similar before, but all childs are then re-rendered every time it hits the limit and a new message comes in. Maybe I am doing it wrong. I will update my post with my writable function

Comment: If you're using an `#each` loop, make sure all messages have an individual key (`{#each messages as message (message.id)}`) so as to optimize re-rendering.

Comment: This is genius ! It won't re-render them anymore. I will do further performance tests and let you know

Comment: Unfortuntely it [seems to suffer from the same problem](https://i.imgur.com/nLDy0gu.png) ... I guess I will quit my idea

Comment: Using a [Virtual List](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-virtual-list) might be an alternative to displaying all 800 messages?

Comment: Tried to build this in a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/473db9f2963d4c58a012d5c98727e4e4?version=3.46.2) - can't see no change there, when the max size is exceeded

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried the Virtual List and it does not seem to play nice with scrollIntoView that I used for auto-scrolling, it also breaks my auto-scroll pause function even after re-writing it. I will completely remake my app in a REPL and see if it loses performance

Comment: Just an update, I [re-did a simple version of my app](https://svelte.dev/repl/8bebc71c155d43b5a387c177831fa5f8?version=3.46.2) with most of your code but I notice now when scrolling noticed it still lags. All I did is add a few spans pretty much, they are the cause of the problem ...

Comment: That's odd, just took a look at your REPL and couldn't notice any lag (FF on MacOS) even when scrolling

Comment: I am on a Windows 10 PC running a 12-core CPU and using Brave browser, I ran the same REPL on Firefox, Edge and Chrome and both Firefox and Edge do not lag, but Brave and Chrome do. The weird thing is that Edge is Chromium based just like Brave and Chrome